# Use python to control computer

Tags: python, operating-system, python-3.6

Do you guys know how to write a program and control a computer (shutdown)? Maybe module OS can answer, but I only know how to use `os.path` and `os.system`.

I've already try this way:

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\Windows\System32')
with open('cmd.exe',encoding='utf-8')as f:
    exec(f.read())
    exec(f.write('shutdown -i'))
```

but shows error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "D:\Mystuff\try.py", line 4, in 
>           exec(f.read())
>
> File "C:\Users\Vic_Lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
>           (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
>       UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: invalid start byte

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, first you don't open `cmd.exe` for reading or writing. Second, you don't try to write to it with `f.write()`. Third, read the documentation for `exec()` at python.org.

Comment: ok ,so how to do that?

Comment: How to *read the documentation for exec() at python.org*? Well, you clearly know how to use a web browser, or you couldn't be here. So type *http://www.python.org* into the address bar, click the link on that page for the documentation, and see if you can work out the rest from there.

Comment: sorry about my grammer-_-.I mean , how can I fix my question..

Answer (score 1):

To shutdown, you don't write to "cmd.exe" file. Instead do this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/s"])
```

/s shutdowns the computer without prompting. To initiate shutdown with a shutdown warning dialog, you can do this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["shutdown", "-i"])
```

Comment: Is module subprocess need to install?

Comment: @ChineseTaipei you could **easily** check yourself and see that it is a standard library module.